# Iterating through multidimensional array in smarty

Tags: php, arrays, smarty

I'm stuck with this multidimensional array handling in smarty (prestashop to be more precise).

I'm having troubles iterating through all the elements.

This is my array, print_r-ed.

```
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [superorder] => 1
            [basket] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [product_name] => iPod shuffle
                            [position_left] => 37
                            [position_top] => 73
                            [order] => 1
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [product_name] => iPod touch
                            [position_left] => 5
                            [position_top] => 66
                            [order] => 2
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [product_name] => iPod Nano
                            [position_left] => 67
                            [position_top] => 49
                            [order] => 3
                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [superorder] => 2
            [basket] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [product_name] => iPod shuffle
                            [position_left] => 37
                            [position_top] => 73
                            [order] => 1
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [product_name] => iPod touch
                            [position_left] => 5
                            [position_top] => 66
                            [order] => 2
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [product_name] => iPod Nano
                            [position_left] => 67
                            [position_top] => 49
                            [order] => 3
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

and this is what I'm trying to use, but failing miserably:

```
{foreach from=$all_baskets name=outer key=superorder item=basket}

    <div superorder="{$basket.superorder}" >


        {foreach from=$basket name=inner key=i item=basket_image}

            <div product_name="{$basket_image.product_name}" order="{$basket_image.order}" style="left:{$basket_image.position_left}px; top:{$basket_image.position_top}px"></div>

        {/foreach}

    </div>

{/foreach}
```

I'm new with smarty and I know I'm doing something wrong, so I was hoping you could help me. Thank you!

Comment: A similar question was asked and answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2562473/php-smarty-loop-multidimensional-array?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

Nevermind guys, I got it. I didn't notice that the sub-array [basket] should be called within second loop level. Here's the solution:

```
{foreach from=$all_baskets name=outer key=superorder item=singlebasket}

            <div class="holder active" superorder="{$singlebasket.superorder}" >

                <span {if $cart_image_url!=""}style="background:url('{$cart_image_url}')"{/if} class="basketbg"></span>

                {foreach from=$singlebasket.basket name=inner key=i item=basket_image}

                    <img class="slot slot-{$basket_image.order}" product_name="{$basket_image.product_name}" src="{$basket_image.url}" order="{$basket_image.order}" style="left:{$basket_image.position_left}px; top:{$basket_image.position_top}px" />

                {/foreach}

            </div>

        {/foreach}
```