# how to use Foreach (smarty) in 3D Array?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, smarty, smarty3

how to use foreach (**smarty**) in 3D Array?

i wish this code to get **cat_title** and **cat_id**

but i dont get **sub_id** and **sub_title**

i get **category** and **subgategory**.

i code in TPL **smary**:

```
{foreach $catData as $cat}
  <ul class="catName">
      <lable>{$cat.cat_title}</lable>
       {foreach $subData as $sub}
            <li class="subName">{$sub.sub_title}</li>
        {/foreach}
   </ul>
{/foreach}
```

**I Array 3D:**

cat_id and cat_title is one item But sub_id and sub_title is more item. All in one Array

**array**(**array**(**cat_id**[one item],**cat_title**[one item],**sub_id**[more item],**sub_title**[more item]))

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [cat_title] => Cat1 
            [cat_id] => 1
            [sub_id] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                    [1] => 2
                    [2] => 3
                    [3] => 4
                )

            [sub_title] => Array
                (
                    [0] => sub1
                    [1] => sub2
                    [2] => sub3
                    [3] => sub4
                )

        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [cat_title] => Cat2
            [cat_id] => 7
            [sub_id] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                    [1] => 2
                    [2] => 3
                )

            [sub_title] => Array
                (
                    [0] => sub1
                    [1] => sub2
                    [2] => sub3
                )

        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [cat_title] => Cat3
            [cat_id] => 11
            [sub_id] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                    [1] => 2

                )

            [sub_title] => Array
                (
                    [0] => sub1
                    [1] => sub2
                )

        )

    [18] => Array
        (
            [cat_title] => Cat4
            [cat_id] => 12
            [sub_id] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                    [1] => 2
                    [2] => 3
                    [3] => 4

                )

            [sub_title] => Array
                (
                    [0] => sub1
                    [1] => sub2
                    [2] => sub3
                    [3] => sub4

                )

        )
)
```

I found the answer:
[php smarty loop multidimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2562473/php-smarty-loop-multidimensional-array)

```
{foreach from=$catData item=catlist}
<ul class="catName">
    <lable data-catid="{$catlist.cat_id}">{$catlist.cat_title}</lable>
    {foreach from=$catlist.sub_title key=k item=sublist}
    <li class="subName" data-subid="{$catlist.sub_id.$k}">{$sublist}</li>
    {/foreach}
</ul>
{/foreach}
```

Answer (score 0):

You found solution that works but it uses Smarty2 syntax and not newer and cleaner Smarty 3 syntax.

In your case if you have:

PHP file:

```
$data = Array
(
    1 => Array
    (
        'cat_title' => 'Cat1',
        'cat_id'    => 1,
        'sub_id'    => Array
        (
            0 => 1,
            1 => 2,
            2 => 3,
            3 => 4,
        ),
        'sub_title' => Array
        (
            0 => 'sub1',
            1 => 'sub2',
            2 => 'sub3',
            3 => 'sub4',
        )

    ),
    7 => Array
    (
        'cat_title' => 'Cat2',
        'cat_id'    => 7,
        'sub_id'    => Array
        (
            0 => 1,
            1 => 2,
            2 => 3,
        ),
        'sub_title' => Array
        (
            0 => 'sub1',
            1 => 'sub2',
            2 => 'sub3',
        )

    )
);


$smarty->assign('catData', $data);
```

Smarty file:

```
{foreach $catData as $cat}
    <ul class="catName">
        <label>{$cat.cat_title}</label>
        {foreach $cat['sub_title'] as $sub}
            <li class="subName">{$sub}</li>
        {/foreach}
    </ul>
{/foreach}
```

The output will be:

```
<ul class="catName">
    <label>Cat1</label>
                <li class="subName">sub1</li>
                <li class="subName">sub2</li>
                <li class="subName">sub3</li>
                <li class="subName">sub4</li>
        </ul>
<ul class="catName">
    <label>Cat2</label>
                <li class="subName">sub1</li>
                <li class="subName">sub2</li>
                <li class="subName">sub3</li>
        </ul>
```

as expected.

If you wanted you could even list over all elements of your arrays.

For the same PHP file you could use the following Smarty file:

```
{foreach $catData as $cat}
    {foreach $cat as $what => $item}
        <strong>{$what}</strong>:
        {if not $item|is_array}
            {$item}
        {else}
            {foreach $item as $value}
                <li class="subName">{$value}</li>
            {/foreach}
        {/if}
        <br />
    {/foreach}
{/foreach}
```

and now will get the following output:

```
<strong>cat_title</strong>:
        Cat1
    <br />
<strong>cat_id</strong>:
        1
    <br />
<strong>sub_id</strong>:
                        <li class="subName">1</li>
                <li class="subName">2</li>
                <li class="subName">3</li>
                <li class="subName">4</li>
                <br />
<strong>sub_title</strong>:
                        <li class="subName">sub1</li>
                <li class="subName">sub2</li>
                <li class="subName">sub3</li>
                <li class="subName">sub4</li>
                <br />

<strong>cat_title</strong>:
        Cat2
    <br />
<strong>cat_id</strong>:
        7
    <br />
<strong>sub_id</strong>:
                        <li class="subName">1</li>
                <li class="subName">2</li>
                <li class="subName">3</li>
                <br />
<strong>sub_title</strong>:
                        <li class="subName">sub1</li>
                <li class="subName">sub2</li>
                <li class="subName">sub3</li>
                <br />
```

You should also work on your HTML output because you cannot put in `<ul>` list elements other than `<li>` and you used here unknown element `<lable>`